# pandas dataframe label columns encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a pandas dataframe with string input columns. df looks like:

```
news                          label1      label2      label3  label4
COVID Hospitalizations ....   health
will pets contract covid....  health      pets
High temperature will cause.. health      weather
...
```

Expected output

```
news                          health      pets      weather  tech
COVID Hospitalizations ....   1           0         0        0 
will pets contract covid....  1           1         0        0
High temperature will cause.. 1           0         1        0
...
```

Currently I used sklean

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df['labels'] = df[['label1','label2','label3','label4']].values.tolist()
mlb.fit(df['labels'])
temp = mlb.transform(df['labels'])
ff = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns = list(mlb.classes_))
df_final = pd.concat([df['news'],ff], axis=1)
```

this works so far.
Just wondering if there is a way to avoid to use `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`     ?

Answer (score 2):

One idea is join values by `|` and then use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
#if missing values NaNs
#df = df.fillna('')
df_final = df.set_index('news').agg('|'.join, 1).str.get_dummies().reset_index()
print (df_final)
                            news  health  pets  weather
0    COVID Hospitalizations ....       1     0        0
1   will pets contract covid....       1     1        0
2  High temperature will cause..       1     0        1
```

Or use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df_final = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('news'), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
              .groupby(level=0,axis=1)
              .max()
              .reset_index())

#second column name is empty string, so dfference with solution above
print (df_final)
                            news     health  pets  weather
0    COVID Hospitalizations ....  1       1     0        0
1   will pets contract covid....  1       1     1        0
2  High temperature will cause..  1       1     0        1
```